# Passing data to bootstrap modal Django template

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The view passes a list of elements to the template, for example a list of movies, and they are rendered in a table. And each element has its detail and one specific element has a list. The content of this list I wanna put them inside a modal. I'm doing this with two for loops like the following:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <td>title</td>
       <td>description</td>
       <td>hours</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for key in movies %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ key.title }}</td>
       <td>{{ key.description }}</td>
       <td>
          <!--This button calls my modal-->
          {% for hour in key.hours %}
             <li>{{ hour }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button>
       </td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My modal is under my table outside the div that wraps my table.
I would like to pass the values of the second for loop to my modal. And when the user clicks on the button the values appear inside the modal.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices

1. You can use Javascript to change the contents of the modal when the button is clicked.
2. Instead of one modal, you create one modal for each movie with its hours. Depending on which button you click, a different modal gets opened.

Answer (score 1):

As @jastr has told, there are two solutions. One of them is doing something like this:

- Wrap your `<li>` elements with a `<ul>`
- Add a class to your button, e.g. `open-modal`
- Add a click listener to your button, and when the user clicks on the
  button, you add the list into your modal

First, some changes on your html:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <td>title</td>
       <td>description</td>
       <td>hours</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for key in movies %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ key.title }}</td>
       <td>{{ key.description }}</td>
       <td>
          <!-- You may want to put this whole list into your modal body -->
          <ul>
          {% for hour in key.hours %}
             <li>{{ hour }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button>
       </td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, you can add a click listener like this to insert the list into your modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.open-modal').click(function (e) {
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html($(this).prev().clone());
    });
</script>
```